# Using GcmNetworkManager on devices running Google Play Services < 7.5.0

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services

I'm using GcmNetworkManager for scheduling my tasks.

But it will not run on devices with google play services version below 7.5.0.

The question is if GcmNetworkManager is not compatible with google play services versions older than 7.5 or have I been doing something wrong.

Also is there any other method to schedule tasks (like how GcmNetworkManager  does) which can be used with older versions of google play services ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GcmNetworkManager was added in Google Play Services 7.5.0, so it will not work on older versions. (Announcement blog post here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/a-closer-look-at-google-play-services-75.html)

However, Google Play Services is automatically updated via Google Play in the background, so users should always have a recent version.

If for some reason you don't want to use GcmNetworkManager, the only other option would be to use the [JobScheduler API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html). This is actually what GcmNetworkManager uses internally on newer devices. The catch is that this API is only available on devices running Android 5.0+. (The big benefit of using GcmNetworkManager is that it includes compatibility code for older devices.)

Alternatively, you could use [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) on older devices, since that's been around since Android 1.0. However, if your task is network-related, you won't get the energy saving benefits that JobScheduler or GcmNetworkManager would otherwise give you.

Comment: Thanks Trevor, isn't there any other API or library which can be used on android 4.0.4+ to achieve this ? I just want to handle some **periodic tasks** and **queue tasks** to be done when network access is regained, if network was not available at the time the task was scheduled.

Comment: @Ali: `AlarmManager` has been around since Android 1.0. However, you will be responsible for detecting whether you have Internet access and dealing with that on your own.

Comment: @CommonsWare Thanks for the reminder about AlarmManager. (Sometimes, it's easy to overlook the simple stuff!) I've updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments